# I'm trying to insert a string into another string without using built-in functions

Tags: c#, string, function

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Your string: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            
            stringFuncs.Insert(str, "Hello", 5);

            
        }
    }

public static string SubString(string word,int a, int b)
        {

            for(int i = a; i < b; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(word[i]);//my substring method
            }
            return word;
        }
public static string Insert(string word, string subs, int index)
        {
            
            int numberOfLetters = 0;
            foreach (var c in word)
            {
                numberOfLetters++;
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine(stringFuncs.SubString(word, 0, index) + subs + stringFuncs.SubString(word, index,numberOfLetters-index));
            return word;

          

        }
```

I'm getting this as output whenever i write something :               My stringHello         My string

my substring method is wrong how can i make it so it only takes the part i needed and returns it back?

Comment: What is `AltDizi`? What do you mean by "why is it takes all the string again"? I'm afraid at the moment I'm finding your question very hard to understand. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit appropriately. Note that your `SubString` method just returns the original string after *printing* part of it - so if you're surprised that it's returning the original string, you should explain what you *expected* it to do.

Comment: Your stringFuncs is obviuosly a class in which you rewrote your SubString and Insert methods. Why not let this class appear in your post? More important: don't use the Console.Write as an output in these methods. It's very confusing. Console.WriteLine can be use in the main part of the program for testing but not the result of a method itself.
There is no need for the Insert method to return the 'word' string, because you use Insert once as a void method.

Comment: And also your a et b arguments are both indexes. So the last call your SubString method must take into account that index is less than the half of the total number of letters. In the standard C# Substring uses an index for the first arg 'a' and a number of chars for 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my method (if you just need a substring method):

```
class Program
{
    static string CustomSubstring(string text, short startIndex, short indexInQuestion)
    {
        short i;
        for (i = startIndex; i < text.Length; i++) ;
        StringBuilder Temp = new StringBuilder();
        //"StringBuilder.Append()" is faster than "string+=string"
        //switch is faster than if
        switch (indexInQuestion < i)
        {
            case true:
                char[] C = text.ToArray();
                for (short j = startIndex; j <= indexInQuestion; j++)
                {
                    Temp.Append(C[j]);
                }
                break;
        }
        return Temp.ToString();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CustomSubstring("Merry Christmas", 6, 14));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> Output: Christmas

Comment: Note: if this solution helps you, please mark as answer (don't forget to vote for me).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution close to yours, with minimal changes, please consider this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Your string: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();                            // Console should be used only in the main part, not the methods
            Console.WriteLine(StringFuncs.Insert(str, "Hello", 5));
            Console.ReadKey();                                          // Waits for the user to press a key
        }
    }

    public class StringFuncs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts a part of a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word"></param> The string you want an extraction from
        /// <param name="startIndex"></param>The position you want tthe extraction to start
        /// <param name="numberOfChars"></param>The number of chars to be extracted
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string SubString(string word, int startIndex, int numberOfChars)
        {
            string result = "";                         // initialisation of the result string
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars; i++)
            {
                result += word[startIndex + i];         // adding chars one by one 
            }
            return result;                              
        }

        // the method below was detached from your old Insert method as it can be re-used
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the number of letter of a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int NumberOfLetters(string word)
        {
            int numberOfLetters = 0;
            foreach (char c in word)    // be explicite, specific and avoid the "var" thing
            {
                numberOfLetters++;
            }
            return numberOfLetters;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts a string into another one, at a given position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetString"></param>The string which will receive the second one
        /// <param name="insertString"></param>The string to be inserted in the first one
        /// <param name="insertPosition"></param>The position of insertion in the first string
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Insert(string targetString, string insertString, int insertPosition)
        {
            return SubString(targetString, 0, insertPosition) + insertString + SubString(targetString, insertPosition, NumberOfLetters(targetString) - insertPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not virtuoso-processing-and-speed argued but shows a more pedagogical approach that you can reproduce in other projects. I just prefer readability and understanding.